is "Gandharva Vivaha" just another term for consensual casual sex with no obligations on either party?
although the physical relationship happens with the woman's consent, is there any obligation on the man to take care of the woman after their union?
Wiki says:

This ancient marriage tradition from the Indian subcontinent was based on consensual acceptance between two people, with no rituals, witnesses or family participation.[1] The marriage of Dushyanta and Shakuntala was a historically celebrated example of this class of marriage.[2]

